# Filter Queryset by field in OnetoOne model

Tags: python, django

I have a model from a 3rd party app that I can't (really don't want to) modify, so I extended it with OnetoOne field like this:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField ....
    content = ....

class ModelExtended(models.Model):
    gallery = models.OneToOneField(Gallery, related_name='galleryextended')
    author = models.Charfield()
```

So what I want to do is create a view for all authors. I want a queryset that contains no more than one object of each author. So if there's 50 Model.objects.all(), but only 2 unique authors entered, only 2 Model objects should be returned.

I've tried:

```
queryset = Model.objects.order_by('author').distinct()
```

which returns:
Cannot resolve keyword 'author' into field. Choices are: date_added, description, modelextended, id, is_public, photos, sites, slug, tags, title

```
queryset=Model.objects.order_by('modelextended.author').distinct()
```

which returns the same as Model.objects.all()

```
queryset = ModelExtended.objects.order_by('author').distinct()
```

which returns no results at all. I am running Postgresql because I read that it only can use .distinct()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
queryset = Model.objects.order_by('modelextended__author').distinct('modelextended__author')
```